# Tomcat cannot start with systemctl on centos7.2

Tags: linux, tomcat

1. CentOS7.2
2. Tomcat9
3. JDK8

I already set `JAVA_HOME` in my evn and run `catalina.sh run` in cammand line, tomcat is start success. But i use `systemctl start tomcat.service` i get a error.

```
11月 04 22:13:02 iZwz90squb7zj67pw5hyizZ systemd[1]: Starting tomcat...
11月 04 22:13:02 iZwz90squb7zj67pw5hyizZ startup.sh[1058]: Neither the     JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
11月 04 22:13:02 iZwz90squb7zj67pw5hyizZ startup.sh[1058]: At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
11月 04 22:13:02 iZwz90squb7zj67pw5hyizZ systemd[1]: tomcat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
11月 04 22:13:02 iZwz90squb7zj67pw5hyizZ systemd[1]: Failed to start tomcat.
11月 04 22:13:02 iZwz90squb7zj67pw5hyizZ systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
11月 04 22:13:02 iZwz90squb7zj67pw5hyizZ systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

Here is my `tomcat.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=tomcat
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/var/run/tomcat.pid
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
ExecStart=/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Hi, I have same problem and did this solution but doesn't works. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` environment variable in the `Service` section of your `tomcat.service` file.

Systemd won't use the environment variables of your shell instance so you need to add them to the configuration.

For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=tomcat
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/var/run/tomcat.pid
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
ExecStart=/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to load in the updates to the service file. You can use `systemctl cat tomcat.service` to verify that the unit file has the change you made.

Comment: `Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8/jre` or `Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8`

Comment: Do you get the same error message or a different one?

Comment: I think you might need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to load in the updates to the service file.

Comment: You could use `systemctl cat tomcat.service` to verify that the unit file has the change you made.

Also, from your previous comment, I think `Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8` is the right value, not the other one.